# How can I see all my Slack activity within a period?

Tags: slack, slackbot

I feel that I could optimize my working style, so I would like a retrospective view on my Slack activity. To see how a typical day of mine actually are with regards to meetings, context shifts and communication.  So concretely I would like a chronological list of the meetings I attended, the messages I send and the messages I received. And the activity I was tagged in in all the channels. I know getting all of this in one query might be to much to ask. But also hints to what queries could help me in investigating my working habits could be beneficial.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for `from: me`, and sort it by `recent` to see the messages you sent in chronological order.

[image: View your Slack activity in chronological order]

Comment: The sorting is called "Newest" now